android webrtc intent leak
I'm trying to create a webrtc app. the connection happens on a foreground service and we cleanup (destroy) the connection in OnDestory state of the service. however I get this error after the CallService is destroyed:
CallService has leaked IntentReceiver org.webrtc.NetworkMonitorAutoDetect@bcf6651 that was originally registered here.

we don't have direct control over this receiver to unregister it and I'm closing the peerConnectionFactory.
What am I missing here?

Have you got soln for this?

While not the perfect solution, the workaround to this problem is to disable the network monitoring via the peerConnectionFactory options parameters like this:
options.disableNetworkMonitor = true

